# range.format.fill is being considered as read-only, but should be read-write

Tags: excel, office-js

When I try to change range.format.fill property, JavaScript raises an error stating that I can't change a read-only property value in strict mode. Maybe format (or fill) object is internally declared as a read-only property and should be read/write? When I try using range.clear, I have success, tough, that's why I assume the error is either in format or fill, but not on range.

The code is:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    // The initialize function must be run each time a new page is loaded
    Office.initialize = function (reason) {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            app.initialize();

            $('#paint-range').click(paintRange);
        });
    };

    function paintRange() {
        Excel.run(function (ctx) {
            var range = ctx.workbook.names.getItem("Countries").getRange();
            range.format.fill = "red";

            return ctx.sync();
        }).catch(function (error) {
            app.showNotification("Error", error);
        })
    }

})();
```

I'm getting the error at:

```
range.format.fill = "red";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you are getting is actually correct.  "Fill" is not a primitive property -- it's an API object (aka "navigation property").  For what you are trying to do, you would need to specify the actual property that you want to modify -- in this case, **color**:

```
range.format.fill.color = "red"
```

For a description of primitive vs. API object properties, see section "Scalar vs. navigation properties – and their impact on load behavior" at http://buildingofficeaddins.com/loading-properties/

Comment: Thanks, Michael! I'll read the link and be more cautious with Excel's JS object model!